# Última celula da linha e coluna Epplus - C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Estou querendo selecionar um range da primeira até a última celula preenchida na linha ou coluna. Em VBA o código fica conforme abaixo usando

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
```

Como poderia fazer da mesma maneira em C# usando Epplus?
Vou partir da celula B139 e preciso ir até a última linha e coluna preenchida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agradeço a atenção de todos.
Consegui encontrar a resposta usando LINQ

Para linha

```
 var lastRowCell1 = worksheet.Cells.Last(c => c.Start.Row == 1);
```

Para Coluna

```
 var lastColCell1 = worksheet.Cells.Last(c => c.Start.Column == 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço muito do pacote Epplus, mas parece resolver o problema usando:

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile)) 
{
   ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
}

var rowCnt = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
var colCnt = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
            //using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;//Inseriri esta linha no inicio das usabilidade;
        //Abre o arquivo execel
        String Destino = @"C:/ST/Informatica/Banco_de_Dados/Clientes.xlsx";
        Excel.Application excelApp_01 = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp_01.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbook wbExcel_01 = excelApp_01.Workbooks.Open(Destino);
        Excel.Worksheet wsPlanilha_01 = (Excel.Worksheet)wbExcel_01.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        //cria as variaveis iniciais
         int MX = 1;
         String valor ="A";
        //percorre todas as linhas até encontar uma vazia
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valor))
        { 
            valor = wsPlanilha_01.get_Range("A" + MX, "A" + MX).Value;
            MX++;
        };
        //insere o dado na ultima linha vazia
        wsPlanilha_01.Cells[MX - 1, 1] = textBox1.Text;
        wsPlanilha_01.Cells[MX - 1, 2] = textBox2.Text;
        wsPlanilha_01.Cells[MX - 1, 3] = textBox3.Text;
        wsPlanilha_01.Cells[MX - 1, 4] = textBox4.Text;

        //Fecha a plicação excel.
        excelApp_01.Visible = true;
        excelApp_01.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
        excelApp_01.Workbooks.Close();
        excelApp_01.Quit();
```